# IP permission problem in Web Service Publish

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a weird case here at work.

The customer(telecommunication firm) has a server which we publish asp.net web service codes which we designed for them. We use that server and web service to get data from the customers own web service and give out for client(telephone) to use it.

The customer does not allow us to code on the remote server, so we have to work on local computer. 
The customer has 2 IPs for its own web services. One of them can be reached only from the remote server, this is an internal IP. Second IP is public which I can reach from my local computer. They address the same methods. For security reasons, they divided IPs.
Everything is fine while developing on local. But when I need to publish web service to the server, I need to change web service URLs to remote servers internal IP. But the local Visual Studio web reference doesn't change web service URLs because it can't reach to service as it is only permitted to reach from the server. So I cannot get a build and publish my code.

Somehow I need to change my visual studio reference URLs to internal IP(so far nobody can reach from local), in order

Hope I am clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be changed from the web.config of your local project.